# Custom type marshalling in IronPython

Tags: c#, numpy, ironpython, math.net

I am working on a numerical program that runs in C# based on Math.NET with scripting abilities using IronPython.  I'd like to have it work so that the Math.NET arrays are converted to NumPy objects as they cross between C# and Python.  There is a NumPy library now for IronPython that I think is mostly compatible.  Does IronPython have a place to register custom type marshalling?

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

http://ironpythonmathnet.codeplex.com/

It's about the older Math.NET Iridium instead of Math.NET Numerics, but I guess the type marshalling would work the same way